# share variables between different html file using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, variables

What is the simplest way to define and access shared variables between .html files belonging to the same project.

Thank you all,

b regards

Answer (score 2):

If you intend for these to be unique for each client, you could:

1. Store cookies
2. Pass data as part of the request parameters

If you intend to store data permanently, you should use a server side language.

The variables you define in any JS file are accessed in exactly the same way. For example, consider the following `variables.js` file which you include at the top of all your pages:

```
var variable1 = "foo";
var variable2 = "bar";
```

Then, in any script that comes after you can simply refer to these variables. Consider mypage.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="variables.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script>
            alert(variable1); // alerts "foo"
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not want to store the data permanently, just need to check the value of shared variables in any of the html files to make changes in the layout of pages.

If a have a file "variables.js" containing the shared variables and including the script on all pages of the project would it be a great option?

b regards

Comment: Can you give me any examples of how to access and modify variables that are within a external ".js" file? thks

Comment: @FábioAntunes I've added an example.

Comment: and how do I change the variable?
sorry for the many questions...
tks again

Comment: @FábioAntunes `variable1 = "changedvalue";`

Comment: ohhh it's the same too... sorry for my last question .. -.-
tks

Comment: Asad, one more question, how can I change the real data in the file. js? in other words, how can I write to the file? 

tks b regards

Comment: @FábioAntunes Now you are starting to move into permanent change territory. It is best to use a server side language for this.

Answer (score 0):

The `sessionStorage` and `localStorage` objects will allow you to share key/string value pairs between .html files, provided they belong to the same domain. `localStorage` values are stored in the browser between sessions, and if the user switches browsers the values will not be carried with them; nor can the server view these values without extra code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_storage

Comment: I do not want to store the data permanently, just need to check the value of shared variables in any of the html files to make changes in the layout of pages.

If a have a file "variables.js" containing the shared variables and including the script on all pages of the project would it be a great option?

b regards

Comment: I think perhaps what you're describing would better be called 'constants' than 'variables', the latter implying that they can change on the fly. If I understand your question correctly then, yes that is a valid approach, although an even better approach would be to do as much as possible of the layout in CSS and share .css files.